# How to submit form by pressing enter or pressing submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've created a form, but it only submits if I press the button Submit... How can I make it also submit if the Enter key is pressed? Here is my form's code:

```
<form method="POST" id="form01">
<textarea name="inputBox123" id="myTextarea" style="white-space:nowrap;">
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Submeter" onclick="myFunction()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction(val) {

var testThis = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;

if ( testThis.indexOf("launch") > -1 ) {
window.location = 'http://www.cateto.weebly.com/benoit.html';
return false;


}

}
</script>
```

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `<input type="button" />`, use `<input type="submit" />` to send the form.

The enter button should submit the form by default.

Answer (score 1):

You should attach event listener to `textarea` tag and listen for `keypress` and when `Enter` is pressed you invoke your function:

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");//get textarea tag
//NOW replace this with: var input = document.getElementById("myTextarea")

//BELOW change textarea with input
textarea.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  console.log(e.which, e.target.value);
  if(e.which === 13)//code number for enter key
    myFunction(e.target.value);//run function with value
});


function myFunction(val) {

var testThis = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;

if ( testThis.indexOf("launch") > -1 ) {
window.location = 'http://www.cateto.weebly.com/benoit.html';
return false;


}

}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="form01">
<textarea name="inputBox123" id="myTextarea" style="white-space:nowrap;">
</textarea>
<!-- change above with input in the comment I entered -->
<input type="submit" value="Submeter" onclick="myFunction()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I want to change my <textarea> to <input>, what changes do I have to do in the JavaScript code, @Bakhtiiar Muzakparov?

Comment: @TomDavies np, `<input type="text" name="inputBox123" id="myTextarea" style="white-space:nowrap;">` , recommend to use https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but it didn't work... I mean, it works, but the function below (if "launch" is submitted then it redirects to a URL) stops working...

Comment: This is much more complex than my answer below, which should work, but if you do need to do this then just change the top line to var textarea = document.getElementById("myTextArea"); That should work, but you then will probably want to rename the textArea var to suit the context.

Comment: @TomDavies I added details how to change it in the comments inside of code

Comment: Thanks! But when I click submit with "launch" written in the input field, it doesn't redirect as it should...